# How do I prevent  Firefox from crashing constantly?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, firefox

Yesterday I bought a new PC. I've carefully chosen the parts, looking for compatibility. But, after I installed 11.04, things are really not working as expected.

My wireless card (RTL8185) is a pain to connect. I have to take the interface down & up everytime my PC boots. (but I'll work on that later).

And, the worst of all, Firefox crashes on almost every page load. I tried to debug it, and it says something related to libfontconfig.so.1 I've spend the last 12 hours googling around with no solutions.

Downloading things from terminal (ie updates) works just fine.

Could some drivers (nvidia, or wifi) be messing with Firefox, causing it to crash?
How can I fix this? I swear I already googled!

When I run it with GDB:

```
Starting program: /usr/lib/firefox-5.0/firefox-bin
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
...
...
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fauld.
0xb6549942 in ?? from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1
```

**[Full Stack Trace with gdb](http://paste.ubuntu.com/665176/)**

I hope anyone can help me here!

Thanks!

**UPDATE-1**
Disabling Pango for Firefox with this line on .bashrc didn't work either.

```
export MOZ_DISABLE_PANGO=1
```

**UPDATE-2**
After trying a lot of things, I've connected a LAN cable to my box and now everything works flawlessly. Too bad my router is far away from my desk. At least, now I know the problem is not Firefox, but my WiFi drivers. I'll post another question regarding my **Wireless card Realtek RTL8185**.

Comment: There is two questions here - please ask two different questions.

Comment: @fossfredom the question is: my firefox hangs, and it throws an error on libfontconfig.so.1, how can I fix it? The wifi issue, is just informative. Also, I have already tried without global menues, but it keeps crashing.

Comment: ok - start firefox from a terminal and copy and paste the output displayed into your question.

Comment: @fossfreedom I've updated my question with gdb output. Thanks!

Comment: is your system fully up to date?

Comment: @fedeisas: Please note that you need to use the [@-syntax](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) in order to reply to people. In order to be able to troubleshoot the crash you need to install the Firefox debug symbol files and obtain an actual stack trace...

Comment: @TomWij I've Firefox debug installed. I've followed MozillaTeam debugging instrucions and here is my stack trace http://paste.ubuntu.com/665176/

Comment: @dustyprogramer Yes, I've just run the updates on my system. Also, I'm running firefox without any plugins (no flash, no global menu)

Comment: Have you tried other browsers, I was just wondering if they do the same. Chromium is a good alternative to try.

Comment: @Col yes, I've tried Chromium and it also crashes (although I haven't debugged the error). As a web developer, I'd prefer to use Firefox (many extensions come handy!). Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Do a memory check if you haven't -- make sure there isn't any physical corruption.  Next, try different versions of firefox -- old stable version, new beta, both from the mozilla site and from repos, ppa's, etc..  Good luck.

Comment: @jgbelacqua can i perform that memory check with my LiveCD? Sorry for the noob question!

Comment: @fedeisas Often this is available as a boot option from BIOS -- that will depend on your hardware.   Something like the memtest burnable iso from http://www.memtest.org/ should also work.  Others might have other suggestions.  This is likely a long shot, but on a new system, it's good to rule out.

Answer (score 1):

I see Pango and Font Config appear again and again.

Can you make sure that [Pango](http://www.pango.org/) is correctly installed and [fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig) is properly configured?

Comment: thanks for answering! I've tried disabling Pango onf Firefox (export MOZ_DISABLE_PANGO=1) but it keeps crashing. How can I make sure that Pango and fontconfig are properly installed and configured? Thanks!

Comment: @fedeisas: Searching for install instructions for them and simply following those, I'm not an Ubuntu user myself but just telling you what I'm seeing and think it could be. Good luck! Don't forget to add extra details and things you already tried to the bottom of your question so people get to read them...